# Deep Link Url open activity after logging the user

Tags: android, android-activity, deep-linking

**How to Open Deep linked Url activity after logging in (Android)?**

Let's us suppose this is the deep linked URL:
*www.xyz.com/articles*

When user will click on this link it will open **MyArticlesActivity**

But what I want is to first allow user to log in and then open this activity.

Comment: put condition onCreate of MyArticlesActivity to check that user is logged in or not

Answer (score 3):

Check out the official android documentation on this link :

https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html

Just put a check for login the in the activity before reading data from intent.
Something like:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);

Intent intent = getIntent();
String action = intent.getAction();
 if(isLoggedIn){    //login check
 Uri data = intent.getData();
 //method call for rest of the activity functions.
 } else {
//Alternate method call or prompt for user login.
  }

}
```

Comment: In addition to this , put data!=null check as well while checking the login. This will prevent other Intent actions like simple navigation between activities.

Comment: Yes. I agree with @KingofMasses

Answer (score 1):

You need to maintain Login Session for your application, by making `Database` or `SharedPrefrence` to hold login details and when your Activity triggers from Deep Link Url you should Check the session in `OnCreate()` for the First time and if the application is already running then put same conditions in `OnNewIntent()` method in your Activity class.

`OnNewIntent()` method is triggered when the targeted Activity is already running.

Answer (score 0):

For That Create Separate Login Activity and use deep linking in that activity once the user logged in pass data from that activity to **MyArticlesActivity**